# Dynamic sql - update table using table variable

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I'd like to update a table in dynamic sql.

```
declare
    x varchar2(10) := 'table_n';
begin
    execute immediate 'update :1 set column_n = 12345' using x;
end;
```

I get ORA-00903: invalid table name

But

```
declare
    x varchar2(10) := 'table_n';
begin
    execute immediate 'update ' || x ||  ' set column_n = 12345';
end;
```

Works.

What's wrong with the first solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot use bind variables for table names in pl/sql

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic sql:

```
1.It generally uses the SQL statements at run time. (for the time which we don't have data at the compilation time).
2. The bind variable , in your query, `x`, uses it on runtime and execute the dynamic on run time. 
3. the bind variable refered by colon is used after USING clause.
```

For more click here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm

Answer (score 0):

[Usage Notes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm)

".... You cannot use bind arguments to pass the names of schema objects to a dynamic SQL statement...."